# Saving PNG logo in CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, png

I need to export a PNG logo which is designed in basic font, the issue that I'm experiencing is that the exported PNG is still fuzzy.

My current settings are:

Font: NTR > smooth 
PNG-24
Transparency checked 
Quality: bicubic

[image: the bottom is really fuzzy]

Comment: Hi Ginger, Is the logo just a font? If the design is more than just text, was the design up-scaled at all? Was it originally created in a vector program? Can you post a picture of the logo or part of it at 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Since the PNG is being displayed on a website, there is a good chance that the code displaying the image is setting a different size than the image actually is. If you provide a link I would be happy to inspect your code for you.

If you are saving PNG-24 with Photoshop you will have a clean crisp image every time.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the link is blu****wink***com without the ***

Comment: Ginger, could you please go into your browser and confirm you browser zoom is at Regular, or 100%. It would appear the logo is in great quality on my system.